# Flutter Countdown Timer milliseconde

Tags: flutter, dart

I just got back to Flutter, and wanted to test the countdown for a simple practice app.
I can scroll the countdown second by second but I haven't figured out how to do it with the milliseconds.

the current code:

```
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';



int _start = 10;
  int _current = 10;

void startTimer() {
    CountdownTimer countDownTimer = CountdownTimer(
      Duration(seconds: _start),
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );

    var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
    sub.onData((duration) {
      setState(() {
        int _current = _start - duration.elapsed.inSeconds;
        dureedefaut = _current;
      });
    });
  }
```

I updated on my page the variable : dureedefaut

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';



int _start = 10;
  int _current = 10;

void startTimer() {
    CountdownTimer countDownTimer = CountdownTimer(
      Duration(milliseconds: _start),
      const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
    );

    var sub = countDownTimer.listen(null);
    sub.onData((duration) {
      setState(() {
        int _current = _start - duration.elapsed.inSeconds;
        dureedefaut = _current;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the solution: const Duration(milliseconds: 1),
        (Timer timer) => setState( ), );

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this :
**Duration(milliseconds: )**

you can use **milisecond** , **second** and etc in Duration Widget